# How can I link 2 files in CodeBlocks without having a project?

Tags: c++, linker, project, codeblocks, header-files

I want to use headerfiles (`header.h` and `header.cpp`), but I'm not using a project. Is there any way to link these files together, or is making a project the only solution?

The problem I encountered right now:

**main.cpp**

```
#include "class.h"

int main()
{
    MyClass test;
}
```

**class.h**

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    int x;
    MyClass();
};
```

**class.cpp**

```
#include "class.h"

MyClass::MyClass() : x(0) {}
```

**ERROR: undefined reference to `MyClass::MyClass()'**

Comment: Hello! Can you clarify what you mean by "link these files together"? Are you asking how to link some existing sources against the definitions in `header.cpp`, how to add `header.h` to your compiler's include path, or something else?

Comment: Make a project. A project is there to capture what you want to build and how.

Comment: @Brian Added an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using a project, then you can't compile it using CodeBlocks. You can compile the code manually, using g++, for example, would be like this: `g++ -o myprog main.cpp class.cpp`. If you are using another compiler, then you will have to look for the command for it.